# Error during setup

Tags: error, magento2.2.2

**version Magento 2.2.2**

> Class Magento\Catalog\Model\View\Asset\Image not found in line 8

**the following file**

```
namespace Vnecoms\Vendors\Model\View\Asset;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Media\ConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Asset\ContextInterface;

class Image extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\View\Asset\Image
{
    /**
     * Image constructor.
     *
     * @param ConfigInterface $mediaConfig
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param EncryptorInterface $encryptor
     * @param string $filePath
     * @param array $miscParams
     */
    public function __construct(
        ConfigInterface $mediaConfig,
        ContextInterface $context,
        EncryptorInterface $encryptor,
        $filePath,
        array $miscParams = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($mediaConfig, $context, $encryptor, $filePath, $miscParams);
    }
}
```

actually this line:

```
class Image extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\View\Asset\Image
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems something wrong with your files, because that file exists in the Magento ver. 2.2.2. You can find it in the official repository and copy to your server https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2.2/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/View/Asset/Image.php

**PS**: I strongly recommend you to check all Magento files.